# Cannot build simple golang code - Slice literal syntax

Tags: go

I am trying to build a simple golang program using `go-dockerclient`

```
package main

import (
        docker "github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient"
)

func main () {
        h := &docker.HostConfig {
                Memory: 4194304,
                MemorySwap: -1,
                CPUShares: 5,
                NetworkMode: "host",
        }
        client, err := docker.NewClient("unix:///var/run/docker.sock")
        config := &docker.Config {
                Env: ["FOO=foo"],
                Image: "redis",
        }
        opts := docker.CreateContainerOptions {
                Config: config,
                HostConfig: hostConfig,
        }
        container, _ := client.CreateContainer(opts)
        err = client.StartContainer(container.ID)
}
```

This gives me:

```
:~/gosrc/src/github.com/achanda$ go build
# github.com/achanda
./main.go:16: syntax error: unexpected comma
./main.go:22: non-declaration statement outside function body
./main.go:23: non-declaration statement outside function body
./main.go:24: non-declaration statement outside function body
./main.go:25: syntax error: unexpected }
```

I don't seem to find anything wrong with the syntax (admittedly a noob though). What is the problem?

Comment: I don't have this package handy, but I am guessing your syntax next to Env is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slice literals should look like this:

```
[]string{"a", "b", "c"}
```

Not like this:

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

So change this:

```
Env: ["FOO=foo"],
```

To this:

```
Env: []string{"FOO=foo"},
```

Comment: Dang, noob mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Admittedly, I have made this mistake a few times too :D

Comment: I have to say, this breaks my intuition about arrays